# JS / React - how to .map two objects at once from within an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm working on a React [Gatsby.js](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/) project. For the search function I've used a plugin called [gatsby-plugin-local-search](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-local-search/)

For this plugin to work I have to run a GraphQL query in the `gatsby-config.js` file. And then the data is processed in the normalizer. Below is an example code of the script. Please note I took out the normelizer. Because my question lays within this and I'll talk more about it below.

```
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-local-search",
      options: {
        name: "pagesNL",
        engine: "flexsearch", // The following engines are supported: flexsearch, lunr
        engineOptions: "speed", // Note: Only the flexsearch engine supports options.
        query: `
          {
            allSanityPage {
              nodes {
                id
                title {
                  _key
                  _type
                  en
                  nl
                }
                _rawBlockRows
                slug {
                  current
                }
              }
            }
            allSanityBlog {
              nodes {
                title {
                  _type
                  en
                  nl
                }
                slug {
                  current
                }
                _id
                _rawBody
              }
            }
          }
        `,
        ref: "id",
        index: ["id", "title", "body"],
        store: ["id", "path", "title"],
        normalizer: ({ data }) => (
            // do something with the data <----------------
        ),
      },
```

As you can see I query `allSanityPage` and `allSanityBlog` . Now the goal is to merge the data and map them at the same time from this script.

## The question

How can I `.map()` them at once?

### first a working example for just `allSanityPage`

```
       normalizer: ({ data }) => (
          data.allSanityPage.nodes.map(node => ({
            id: node.id,
            path: node.slug.current,
            title: localizeData(node.title, "nl"),
            body: localizeData(node._rawBlockRows, "nl"),
          }))
       ),
```

I'm looking for a way tot populate it with both objects `data.allSanityPage.nodes` and `data.allSanityBlog.nodes`

I thought something like this would work:

```
{...data.allSanityPage.nodes, ...data.allSanityBlog.nodes}.map()
```

But that obviously doesn't work

(I'm not worried about the `body:` since I would conditionally check it like `body: (node._rawBlockRows) ? localizeData(node._rawBlockRows, "nl"): localizeData(node._rawBody, "nl"),`
`

Comment: How do you want to match objects from both arrays for the merge? By id? And what should happen to equal properties like 'title'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your idea was good when you tried `{...data.allSanityPage.nodes, ...data.allSanityBlog.nodes}.map()`

The error is that you `.map()` one object, which doesn't have that function in his prototype.

Try `[...data.allSanityPage.nodes, ...data.allSanityBlog.nodes].map(...`

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: This! Thanks Andrea. That did the trick. Thought I was going crazy. #deadlineStress

Answer (score 0):

You can do by nest map func in the first mapping func

```
 normalizer: ({ data }) => (
      data.allSanityPage.nodes.map(node => 
          data.allSanityBlog.nodes.map(node2 =>
             //your code
             )
           )
```

An example of this is

```
a.map(e1 => b.map(e2 => 
     console.log(e1 == e2)))
```

Comment: You have to watch out, since you are looping through `allSanityBlog.nodes` for each node in allSanityPage.nodes. Like this there would be a lot of duplicates and the number of  iterations would be the n*m instead of n+m, where n and m are the respective length of both the initial arrays